# How long does WorkManager persist failed jobs?

Tags: android, androidx, android-workmanager

I have a scenario where I want to retry recently failed jobs but workmanager returns all failed jobs. Is there way to remove old jobs?

Answer (score 2):

For `OneTimeWorkRequest`, FAILURE it's a final status. It's not going to be re-executed. For `PeriodicWorkRequest` it is different. Check this blogs:

- [Introducing WorkManager](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/introducing-workmanager-2083bcfc4712)
- [WorkManager Periodicity](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-periodicity-ff35185ff006)

Also [this video](https://www.droidcon.com/media-detail?video=352671730) covers this.

Back to your question:

> Is there a way to remove old jobs?

Yes!

Use [`WorkManager#pruneWork()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#pruneWork()) to remove jobs in a final state (SUCCEEDED, FAILED and CANCELLED). As you can see from the docs, this method has to be used with caution.

Keep in mind that this removes all jobs that is in the failed state. A way to remove old jobs, is to reduce the amount of time that WorkRequests are keeped in WorkManager's DB setting a custom retention value when you build them. For this use [`WorkRequest#keepResultsForAtLeast(long duration, TimeUnit timeUnit)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkRequest.Builder.html#keepResultsForAtLeast(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

Answer (score -2):

Definitely there is a way to cancel works from `WorkManager`.

To cancel works from `WorkManager` you just need to save the UUID of Works.

And you will be able to cancel any work by this piece of code -

```
WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelWorkById(UUID); [Deprecated]
```

**Edit:**
You can cancel like below - Taken from - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work#cancelling

```
// by id
workManager.cancelWorkById(syncWorker.id);

// by name
workManager.cancelUniqueWork("sync");

// by tag
workManager.cancelAllWorkByTag("syncTag");
```

Under the hood, WorkManager checks the State of the work. If the work is already finished, nothing happens. Otherwise, the work's state is changed to CANCELLED and the work will not run in the future. Any WorkRequest jobs that are dependent on this work will also be CANCELLED.

Currently RUNNING work receives a call to ListenableWorker.onStopped(). Override this method to handle any potential cleanup. See stop a running worker for more information.

Comment: OneTimeWorkRequest that return Failed, are never restarted automatically by WorkManager,